# How to enable TCP/IP PROTOCOL for SQL Server Developer Edition on Linux/CENTOS

Tags: sql-server, centos7

I have proved that when installing SQL Server 2019 developer edition, you have to go to Configuration Manager after the installation and enabled TCP/IP protocol because it is disabled by default after the installation. Because Configuration Manager is a GUI, it is easy to do this in Windows.

However, I am not using Windows and I have installed SQL Server 2019 on Centos 7 and 8 and selected the Developer Edition (or Express edition for that matter).  TCP/IP protocol is disabled because I cannot connect to my SQL Server.

I need to know how to enable TCP/IP protocol on Linux/CentOS for SQL Server instance after it's been installed. I did find an article somewhere that tabled the protocols and TCP/IP is disabled for Developer/Express etc. edition.

Has anyone else run into this issue and can assist?

My odbc.ini looks like this:

```
[MSSQLTest]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = 192.168.1.155
port=1433
database=siebeldb
```

Many thanks

Comment: I am able to telnet to the server on port 1433:   Trying 192.168.1.155...
Connected to 192.168.1.155.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: If you are able to telnet to it on port 1433 then it is already listening with TCP/IP. SQL Server 2017/2019 for Linux listens on TCP/IP by default and the port can be reconfigured with `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set network.tcpport NEW_PORT` followed by `sudo systemctl restart mssql-server` to make the change take effect. ref: [Configure SQL Server settings on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#tcpport).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue and it was not around the TCP/IP protocol being enabled or not.

The order of the parameters in the odbc.ini seems to have solved the issue for me:

This did NOT work:

```
[MSSQLTest]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=MS SQL
Database = siebeldb
Servername = 192.168.1.155
Port = 1433
```

This DID work:

```
[MSSQLTest]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server  
Server = 192.168.1.155
port=1433
database=siebeldb
```

I am now able to get a "Connected" when issuing the isql command.

Regards